# Need to identify type of View

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

Android. API 16 (I know, is old but I can't change)

I need to identify the type of view in focus programmatically.
I have a thread capable to generate data but not always the correct view is in focus (EditText).
I need to check, when the data are ready, if the current view in focus can handle the data.
If yes, ok, if not the data are just discarded/lost.
I know that one of the possible View in focus can be a ListView.

What is the best way to do so ?

I did try with activity.getCurrentFocus().getContentDescription() but it crash.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you could use [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html).

```
if (activity.getCurrentFocus() instanceof ListView){
    // do whatever
} else {
    // do other
}
```

Another option would be checking for reference equality. If you have a reference to the views you expect could be in focus, simply check each:

```
View inFocus = activity.getCurrentFocus()
if (inFocus == myView){
    // do whatever
} else if (inFocus == myOtherView){

} else {...}
```

Comment: The check if (activity.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText)   worked perfectly !
Thanks !